# Make Border for ImageButton when onfocus without changing background pic Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml, imagebutton

I make program for Android tv box with remote control ... i use ImageButtons to view film posters . I want to make yellow border on the currently focused ImageButton without changing the background image.
Note: the images are being downloaded from server and i set it dynamically .[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the ImageView you can add the image poster in the `android:src` also in the `android:background` you make it the color you want for your border.

Dont add padding to the ImageView.

Programatically each time you focus the ImageView what you do is add padding to the ImageView so the background will show. the padding will be the thickness of the border